# Matrix rows notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I'm working with a set of $M$ vectors $ \{\mathbf{w}_i \in \mathbb{R}^N, \, i = 1, \ldots, M \}$. Since single vectors are usually considered as column vectors, I'm defining a matrix

$$
\mathbf{W} = [\mathbf{w}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{w}_M] \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}
$$

by placing the vectors as matrix columns.

However, for some descriptions, I need to refer to the matrix **rows**.

Is there an elegant notation to refer to this matrix rows (preferably with less notation overhead)?

Comment: What about $\mathbf{W}_{i\bullet}$ for the $i$th row?

Comment: Since I'm writing vectors in lower case I would write matrix rows as $\mathbf{w}_{j*}$ for $j = 1, \ldots, N$. However, I'm not sure if this dot or star symbol is a valid math notation.

Comment: It's very common. But even if it wasn't, you can always invent your own notation, as long as you define it so that readers know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can represent the rows of $\mathbf W$ by the  $N$ - (column) vectors of $\mathbf W^{\mathsf T}$: $$\mathbf w'_i :=\mathrm{col}_i\mathbf W^\mathsf T\quad(i=1,\dots,N).$$ There is no standard notation for this; I chose the prime notation for convenience. You would also need to state your chosen notation explicitly.

Answer (score 16):

Since $W_{nm}$ is unambiguous for the $n$th row, $m$th col entry of $W$, I quite like the following notation of using a star, dot, or  colon as a placeholder for the other dimension (similar to how dot or star can be used as omitted entries in a matrix):

- For rows: $W_{n*}$ or $W_{n,*}$ (or $W_{n\cdot}$ or $W_{n:}$)
- For cols: $W_{*m}$ or $W_{*,m}$ (or other symbols likewise)

From a programming perspective, this is similar to how in R we simply leave off the other dimension, writing `W[n,]` and `W[,m]`, and in Numpy we use a colon to represent the entire other axis with `W[n,:]` and `W[m,:]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you write
$$\mathbf{W} = [\mathbf{w}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{w}_M]^t \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$$
then the rows of $\mathbf W$ are $\mathbf{w}_1^t, \ldots, \mathbf{w}_M^t$.

Comment: Well, yes, but that's *not* how $\mathbf{W}$ was written (nor is it even necessarily of the correct dimension), so how does this help?

Comment: It's additional notation.  Just use a different letter and set it equal to the original.  Not that hard.